# How to display Alert Popups at different intervals on any Activity

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver

Server sends some discount information, or some video, or other data, and all users who are using the application 
will display that message or video in an alert dialog of any activity.

There is a library called [Insert.io](https://www.insert.io/)   , that do the job, but my question is that, is there any
way that android provides by which we can achieve this, without using any 3rd party library.

I google this, and according to my understanding we can use `broadcast receiver` to achieve this, but i am still 
unsure that is this the only way, or will it work with server, and trigger itself whenever server send some data to 
Client.

Kindly guide me about this

Answer (score 0):

I think we can.

Create a abstract Activity. this Activity register broadcast receiver listen server.

Other Activity extends from this Activity.

sorry. I have not enough reputation to comment :)

Answer (score 0):

You are right, easiest way is to use `PushNotifications` and receive them in your implemented `BroadcastReceiver`.

Then, in my opinion, the safest and easiest option would be to use one main `Activity` with the different fragments you need for your app.

Declare your custom `AlertDialog` and `BroadcastReceiver` in your main `Activity` and you will be able to show the dialog independently the fragment you are showing in that moment.

Hope it helps :)